# why is angular universal giving me a Routing error

Tags: angular, angular-universal

When serving my angular universal application I get this error thrown at me in the console

```sh
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
```

This happens only when serving through the universal server.ts, if I try to serve the application via

```sh
ng serve
```

Everything works flawlessly.

The thing i already tried:

- I put `enableTracing: true,` inside my `RouterModule.forRoot` in my routing component and there i find this which leads me to believe its a Scroll problem

```
Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')

Router Event: Scroll

Scroll {
  routerEvent: NavigationEnd {
    id: 1,
    url: '/dettaglio-annuncio/annuncio-a-via-a-daosta-11-li-116-78528697',
    urlAfterRedirects: '/dettaglio-annuncio/annuncio-a-via-a-daosta-11-li-116-78528697'
  },
  position: null,
  anchor: null
}

Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.

Router Event: NavigationStart

NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/null')
NavigationStart {
  id: 1,
  url: '/null',
  navigationTrigger: 'imperative',
  restoredState: null
}

Router Event: NavigationError

NavigationError(id: 1, url: '/null', error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null')

NavigationError {
  id: 1,
  url: '/null',
  error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
```

As you can see in the `Router Event: Scroll` position and anchor are null, and after receiving that event (I couldn't figure out what fires it), an event of tipe NavigationStart is fired but it's wrong because the url is set to `/null`

```
NavigationStart {
  id: 1,
  url: '/null',
  navigationTrigger: 'imperative',
  restoredState: null
}
```

Which obviously makes the app throw an error, stalls the entire web application and is driving me insane.

Here's my server.ts :

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

import {AppServerModule} from './src/main.server';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {existsSync} from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/PROJECT_NAME/browser'); //obscured for client privacy
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, {req, providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl}]});
  });

  // server.get('/:routeParam', (req, res) => { res.render(indexHtml, {req}); //note 'index' uses the Universal engine })

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

**EDIT: Here's the route file**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'ricerca-annuncio',
    component: RicercaAnnuncioComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '**',
        component: RicercaAnnuncioComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'ricerca-agenzia',
    component: RicercaAgenziaComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'ricerca-agente',
    component: RicercaAgenteComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'dettaglio-annuncio/:id',
    component: DettaglioAnnuncioComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrum: 'Dettaglio Annuncio',
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'dettaglio-agenzia/:id',
    component: DettaglioAgenziaComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrum: 'Dettaglio Agenzia',
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'dettaglio-agente/:id',
    component: DettaglioAgenteComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrum: 'Dettaglio Agente',
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'ricerca-su-mappa',
    component: RicercaSuMappa,
  },
  {
    path: 'utente',
    component: ProfiloUtenteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
  },
  {
    path: 'utente-annunci',
    component: AnnunciSalvatiComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'utente-ricerche',
    component: RicercheSalvateComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabled',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Maybe show some of the routes? Like a few possible routes you could be trying to match?

Comment: I edited the question with the route file

Comment: Can you show how you're triggering the route (the routerLink)? If you're using a variable are you sure is not empty/null?